# Nestjs: How to inject models in a separate module?

Tags: module, nestjs

I have an Inventory entity file and I want to use the Inventory in a separate module like following:

```
@Injectable()
export class InventoryConsumer implements OnModuleInit {
    private consumer: Consumer;
    

    constructor(private readonly kafka: Kafka,@InjectModel(Inventory.name) private inventoryModel: Model<Inventory>) {}

    async consumeInventoryMessages(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.consumer.run({
                eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }: EachMessagePayload) => {
                    const inventory = message.value.toString();
                    this.inventoryModel.insertMany(JSON.parse(inventory)); // I WANT TO INSERT RECORDS.
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.trace('Error while consuming inventory messages', error);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the InventoryConsumer method in the kafka.service.ts file like this and passing the Inventory model:

```
@Injectable()
export class KafkaService implements OnModuleInit {
    private kafka: Kafka;
    private readonly kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig;
    private inventoryproducer: InventoryProducer;
    private inventoryConsumer: InventoryConsumer;

    constructor(@InjectModel(Inventory.name) private inventoryModel: Model<Inventory>) {
        this.kafkaConfig = {
            brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
        };
        this.kafka = new Kafka(this.kafkaConfig);
        this.inventoryConsumer = new InventoryConsumer(this.kafka, inventoryModule);
        this.inventoryproducer = new InventoryProducer(this.kafka);
    }

    async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
        await this.inventoryConsumer.consumeInventoryMessages();
    }

    getInventoryConsumer(): InventoryConsumer {
        return this.inventoryConsumer;
    }

    getInventoryProducer(): InventoryProducer {
        return this.inventoryproducer;
    }
}
```

but I am getting the error: `Error: A circular dependency has been detected inside InventoryModule. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()".`

The inventory module:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        DatabaseProviderModule,
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Inventory.name, schema: InventorySchema }]),
        ...other models
    ],
    controllers: [InventoryController],
    providers: [InventoryService, KafkaService],
})
export class InventoryModule {}
```

The kafka module file which contains the InventoryConsumer and InventoryProducer files:

```
@Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Inventory.name, schema: InventorySchema }])],
    providers: [KafkaService],
    exports: [KafkaService],
})
export class KafkaModule {}
```

How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a module imported by InventoryModule also imports InventoryModule (thus there is a circular dependency).

You have two options:

- Rethink your logic: maybe your imports are incorrect. It feels like InventoryModule would import utilities and would be imported by a more general app/module.
- use `forwardRef()` so both modules can import each other. [See documentation here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#forward-reference)